# Store data to MySQL using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

How do I add multiple data entries using AJAX? I found this snippet online:`

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "../php/saveEntry.php",
          data: {id: someID}
          dataType: "html"
    });
```

`

So basically i want to ad multiple input id's.. do i just do this?

```
id: someID, id: someID, id: someID
```

or is each ID wrapped in {} curly brackets?

Please tell me if my question is unclear.

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the data attribute:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "../php/saveEntry.php",
          data: {
              id: $("#someid").val(),
              price: $("#somepriceid").val(),
              qty: $("#textAreaId").text()
          },
          dataType: "html"
    });
```

Comment: this does not answer the question

Comment: The data im trying to send is inputs from a form.. so ive got 4 inputs:

<textarea id="inputMessage"></textarea>
<select id="inputOS"></select>
<input type="text" id="inputName" >
<input type="text" id="inputEmail" >

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#id").each(function(index, value){
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "../php/saveEntry.php",
          data: {
                id: $("#id").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                name: $("#inputName").val(),
           },
          dataType: "html"
    });
```